# Sharing data between threads using blockingqueues questions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
protected BlockingQueue<DataPack> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<DataPack>(1024);
```

i have been using the code above for quite a while and i have never quite understood it, i mean i know how to use it to do what i need it to do but i dont know the diffrences between the arrayblockingqueue and whatever types there may be, so would someone mind explain this and also explain when to use each one. also would you mind giving me some info about the speed of this and better alternatives if any and is there a chance i will lose data? (i can lose some data but i carnt be losing like 10% of the data being shared.)

Thanks

Comment: *"diffrences between the arrayblockingqueue and whatever types there may be"* is a little broad. Do you mean a comparison with other BlockingQueues?

Comment: Read the javadoc. It's all explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to lose any data. That queue exists in-process and simply holds object references inserted by one thread, and taken by a second. It's a normal Java collection but with synchronised (thread-aware/thread-safe) mutators.

With respect to speed, I suspect any differences are going to be negligible. As ever, you should measure if it's of concern, but I suspect the fact that you have two threads means you have latencies elsewhere, and the presence of the queue won't impact that at all.